# Django Alter commandline filter to use in project

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-filter

So since i've been trying to learn django there is one thing that confuses me more than anything else, and that is getting something that works in the django shell into a format that works in models.py of views.py. So here is an example from the Documentation:

```
>>> Entry.objects.all().filter(pub_date__year=2006)
```

So I can work with the shell, there are loads of examples everywhere, what never seems to be covered is how you then put this in your code if you want to filter for other years for example. Can someone explain this or point me at documentation that explains this, as I've not found it in the django docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do that, but for the beginning and learning purposes your view should accept a year argument:

```
def my_view(request, year):
    entries = Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__year=year)
    context = {
        "entries": entries
    }
    return TemplateResponse(request, 'my_template.html', context)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, the question I have, is where does the 'year' variable come from, is this where we enter the world of *args and **kwargs and is it actually passed back by the template?

Comment: it is in your URL `/my-view/2006/` it can be in the template if you add it to the context `"year": year`

Comment: Thanks that makes a bit more sense. Have an answered tick.

Answer (score 1):

The line you are talking about is used to query the database and then filter things. This line is mostly used in views or serializers since you want the entries to be passed on to either template or as JSON to API response.

Using it in views:

```py
    def view(request):
        entries = Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__year=year)
        return render(request, 'index.html', {'entries': entries})
```

Here the object `{'entries': entries}` in above code is context object.

And then after that, you can use the same thing in Django Templates for example here in index.html

```html
   {% for entry in entries %}
       <li> {{ entry.id }} </li>
   {% endfor %}
```